Ciclo para subir dato por dato de un excel a una pagina web
Estoy buscando la forma en la que pueda tomar el dato de una celda de Excel y subirlo a una página web y que este se esté ciclando hasta que la columna de mi Excel se quede sin datos. Lo he intentado con el ciclo for pero hasta el momento solo sube un dato y no avanza a tomar el siguiente, todo esto lo estoy haciendo en jupyter con selenium
La variable entrada la defino como el dato que se va a tomar para ingresarse ahi.
Primero se debe de tomar el dato de la columna para para ingresarse en LP y luego tomar el dato de la siguiente celda de la misma columna para ingresarse en suministro, y se regresare para ingresar el de la siguiente celda otra vez en lp y así hasta terminar los datos
archivo = r"encale de archivo"
df = pd.read_excel(archivo)
df

LP = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'LINK PARA INGRESAR EL DATO').send_keys(entrada)

OK = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'LINK PARA INGRESAR EL DATO).click()

SUMINISTRO = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'LINK PARA INGRESAR EL DATO').send_keys(entrada)

OK1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'LINK PARA INGRESAR EL DATO').click()

